# How to programmatically check if running on HHVM?

Tags: php, hhvm

I need to run a given package on both **HHVM** runtime and traditional **PHP** runtime. My question: is there a way to check **programmatically** if current environment is HHVM? Something like this:

```
<?php
if(running_on_hhvm()) {
    // do hhvm compatible routine
}
else {
    // do normal routine
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can utilise the constant `HHVM_VERSION` specific to HHVM:

```
if (defined('HHVM_VERSION')) {
    // Code
}
```

You can put this in your own function if you want.

```
function is_hhvm() {
    return defined('HHVM_VERSION');
}

if (is_hhvm()) {
    // Code
}
```

Source: http://www.hhvm.com/blog/2393/hhvm-2-3-0-and-travis-ci

Comment: Great! Missed that post. Personally, I prefer to wrap this logic on a function or method.

Answer (score -2):

Some older versions of HHVM don't have HHVM_VERSION defined. They all output "HipHop" in phpinfo().

```
function is_hhvm(){
  ob_start();
  phpinfo();
  $info=ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return ($info=='HipHop');
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. We'll make `phpinfo` be more like PHP5 at some point.